# Extend iOS Development Certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

Sorry for the stupid question, but it is not possible to extend an iOS Development Certificate? IMHO this was previously possible? I have only 8 days left, but have only the option to revoke the certificate. I only find some hints to renew the certificate, but I want to extend the existing one.

Comment: You can't extend. Create a new one. This must be done every year.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) for guidance on how to replace expired certificates. "Replacing Expired Certificates" part is almost at the end of the page.

Comment: Really... Ok thank you for this information. Than I would renew my certificate... every year :(